# Is it possible to merge two google cloud storage files into one

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to merge two google spread sheets or two regular documents into one document and return it to the client. Here is something for compositing objects :
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects
using google cloud storage client, but I don't understand it. For example in the "Performing Object Composition with the JSON API" section there are:

```
"name": "component-obj-1"
"name": "component-obj-2"
```

etc..

If this component is data component using this POST request may be is possible to write these two components into one new object that is file saved on cloud storage.

Comment: The compose operation composes the bytes. It has no knowledge of the content-type, so it wouldn't know how to merge the spreadsheets.

Comment: So then it's not possible. You can add this as an answer if you want . Thank you. What I don't understand is what is this used for, I mean composing the bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not byte, but object composition. It is useful for sequential files, like csv, txt or log files, or chunks for the same object. Compositing the chunks will give the original object back. As jterrence explained, this won't merge two formatted files into one. Have a look [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/e_DnPvbgvo4) too, where they elaborate further on the topic.